# php upload_max_filesize problem

Tags: php, unix, hosting

am working on a website and i have a big problem when i tried to upload files, i increase upload_max_filesize and post_max_size and the code still understand only as a max. 10M. for any different folder php accepts 100M. but inside the site folder ( which am working inside) it doesn't understand it. i check for local php.ini or .htaccess.

note: am running a linux server.

Comment: yes, @pawtac. it's weired because the the only folder am in has 10M as max and all the others has 100M. and there is no local php.ini or . htaccess

Comment: the site folder has max 10M and Omar(rest of folders) has 100M http://pbf.org.ps/site/upload.php http://pbf.org.ps/omar/upload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading bigger files I would suggest a dedicated uploader plug-in.

Like a SWF of Java. For these reasons:

- Security - you can easily encode the sent data (encoding **ByteArray** in AS3.0 is very easy, can be even tokenized so it is hard to intercept the stream)
- Reliability - with simple HTTP requests it is hard to actually monitor the upload progress, so the user might choose to close the uploaded (because he thinks it got stuck)
- User friendly - again, progress bar
- Not limited by server - if you accept it directly with PHP custom code, you won't need any configuring for annoying things like max file size on upload.

On server-side you will need either a Socket listener, or an HTTP tunnel if unavailable.

Comment: For security using SSL would probably be better.

Comment: Sure would, but it might not be accessible... By the Socket listener I meant any port but HTTP - might be HTTPS, SSL, FTP, SFTP... custom port...

Comment: thanks @Aurel300, but am trying to solve max_upload_size. and understand why it's happening ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JumpLoader](http://jumploader.com/), which is a Java applet, and it is able to [split large files into partitions](http://jumploader.com/doc_partupload.html), and upload them one by one. Then a [PHP script rebuilds the original file](http://jumploader.com/doc_serverside.html) from the uploaded partitions on the server.

Answer (score 1):

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) can split large files into smaller chunks. See the [documentation](http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php).

Answer (score 1):

Do you run Apache with **mod_security**? Then check if the `LimitRequestBody` is in affect. 
Here is a good tutorial about [Settings for uploading files with PHP](http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,
I found the problem. i don't know why is the file is not visible for me /public_html/site/.htaccess

i tried to overwrite it, and it's seems to be working.

Thanks a lot for efforts.